# Overlay Border Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay a border image in between a div with a transparent background color and the outter non-background color so it's between containers and looks more stiched on. I get it working but for some reason it put it *behind* the background making the image more transparent than present / visible. Here's what I've got:

```css
.colWrap {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 6px;
    border-width: 7px;
       -moz-border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJjI9.png') 6 round;
    -webkit-border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJjI9.png') 6px round;
         -o-border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJjI9.png') 6 round;
            border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJjI9.png') 6 round;
}

.colWrap .col {
    margin: -4px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba( 254, 250, 100, 0.65 );
    width: 275px;
    height: 315px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colWrap">  
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="colWrap">  
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried making the `.colWrap` container relative and the `.col` absolute with z-indices but it made no difference, it always end up behind the semi-transparent background. Is there any way around this or will it always be this way?

Comment: May not be what you want but you can assign the background color to the `colWrap` and achieve the desired look.

Comment: Thanks! The desired goal is to have the background image between the `.col` background color and the white body color instead of on top of the background color. @TimLewis - The reason I reverted it was to keep the snippet runner. I'll update the BG Color

Comment: @Howdy_McGee No problem, I have a very light screen is all, I couldn't tell the image apart from the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this to .col

```
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
```

Comment: Just a notice for future readers, while this *does* work, since the inner container is -1 text becomes unavailable for highlighting.